How to vary both color and size of circles using expressions?
I created a MapServer WMS point layer with circle symbols. I would like to vary both circle size and color by expression - is that possible, if yes how?
As a workaround, I reverted to classifying circle size (6 discrete bins, not continuous) in the data source as "size" and applying this field as SIZE. Below are two example classes:
  CLASS
    NAME "Öl"
    EXPRESSION ([source] = 1)
    STYLE
      SYMBOL "circle"
      COLOR "#ff7301"
      SIZE [size]
      OPACITY 70
      OUTLINECOLOR "#000000"
      OUTLINEWIDTH 1
    END
  END
  CLASS
    NAME "Gas"
    EXPRESSION ([source] = 2)
    STYLE
      SYMBOL "circle"
      COLOR "#ffd92f"
      SIZE [size]
      OPACITY 70
      OUTLINECOLOR "#000000"
      OUTLINEWIDTH 1
    END
  END


There is an example in https://mapserver.org/mapfile/style.html about COLOR [MYPAINT].

Thanks @user30184 but using an attribute is what I would like to avoid. I am looking for a solution to use two expressions (one for color, one for size) so that I do not need to encode any symbol style in the data.

If the documentation is right https://mapserver.org/mapfile/expressions.html#introduction then expressions cannot be used for that purpose. Maybe you could use a workaround by using some clever SQL in the DATA for creating "size" and "color" attributes on-the-fly, using CASE in the SQL.

@user30184 Thank you. I had read that, but still wasn't sure if I can build classes dynamically from two rules.
SQL: I just realized you mean SQL in the DATA object like here. Thanks for pointing this out. I'll try it as it would satisfy my requirement behind this post: to separate data and config.
